# How to apply horizontal margin to TabBar Widget which should clip it's margin on scroll

Tags: css, flutter, dart

[image: This is the current tabbar I have placed]

I need to add a margin horizontally and on scroll, the margin space should not be visible

And I achieve this pattern by using,

```html
Stack(
                    fit: StackFit.passthrough,
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade600, width: 1.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 25,
                        child: TabBar(
                          isScrollable: true,
                          controller: ticketsProvider.tabController,
                          unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xffAAAAAA),
                          indicatorWeight: 1,
                          labelColor: Colors.black45,
                          onTap: (index) {
                            // Tab index when user select it, it start from zero
                          },
                          tabs: [
                            AdminTicketWidgets.tabBar(title: "Tab One", isPadding: false),
                            AdminTicketWidgets.tabBar(title: "Tab two", isPadding: false),
                            AdminTicketWidgets.tabBar(title: "Tab three", isPadding: false),
                            AdminTicketWidgets.tabBar(title: "Tab four", isPadding: false),
                            AdminTicketWidgets.tabBar(title: "Tab five", isPadding: false),
                            AdminTicketWidgets.tabBar(title: "Tab six", isPadding: false),
                          ],
                        ),)
                    ],
                  ),
```

Here I am attaching AdminTicketWidgets class

```html
class AdminTicketWidgets {
  static tabBar({required title, isPadding}) {
    return Tab(
        icon: Container(
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

And I have reached close to the design by wrapping Tabbar with Row which first and last

```
SizedBox(width:16)
```

But the line under the tab using stack lets troubles the design.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Kindly let me know your suggestions on this

Comment: means have some space on left & right? & can you include more about `AdminTicketWidgets` or simplify the widget

Comment: Sorry didnt get what exactly you are trying to get. do you mean margin should be always visible ?

Comment: No, it should not visible on the scroll.

Comment: even after setting padding, it is getting space -; Got it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly play with `labelPadding`, `indicatorPadding` and `Tab`'s `iconMargin`

Change the padding value based on your need.

```dart
child: TabBar(
  isScrollable: true,
  indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, //this is the thing you are looking for 
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

Comment: I tried the above code. That adds space in each tab. But the design needs space only at both ends.

Comment: try to use `EdgeInsets.only(right:`